# Creating an array of struct inside another struct and accessing the members of the struct inside the array in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I'm tring to create struct (defined with typedef) array inside another struct (also defined with typedef) and access the members of the struct inside the array, but I'm kind of stuck. I really appreciate if you could guide me to the right direction.

My code is on a part of a bigger code, so I will try to explain my situation with an example code. If its not understood, I can always share my actual code.

I have two structs in a header file;

```
#define MAX_COMP_COUNT 64

typedef struct Module Module;
typedef struct Component Component;

struct Module
{
    Component** _CompArr[MAX_COMP_COUNT];
    uint8_t _CompCount;

};

struct Component
{
    uint8_t _page, _id;
};
```

I wanted to add the Component structs inside the array in the Module struct (Dynamic size is not needed at the moment.)

So I wrote this function in an .c file;

```
uint8_t AddComp(Module* mod, Component* _comp, uint8_t __page, uint8_t __id)
{
    //Pass the corresponding data from component to component struct
    _comp->_id = __id;
    _comp->_page = __page;

    //Add the component struct to the list on the Module Struct
    mod->_CompArr[mod->_CompCount] = &_comp;
    mod->_CompCount++;

    //Return OK
    return 0;
}
```

However I'm trying to access to the id member of the struct through the array but I kind of failed. I don't know if I misused something or the parts above are defined wrong. It would be so helpful if you could correct me. Thanks in advance.

```
uint8_t Module_Update(Module *mod)
{
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < mod->_CompCount; i++)
    {
        //This part is not working
        if(*(mod->_CompArr[i])->_id == 0xFF)
            //Do stuff
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I'm getting this error;

error: '*mod->_CompArr[(int)i]' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?

Comment: What's the deal with the double pointers? Seems very superfluous

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Please include output from this code? If I had to guess, you're missing a parentheses around `(*(mod->_CompArr[i]))->`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for the comment. I included the error message I got. Other parts of the code seems correct, or at least compiles, I got the error on the last part.

Comment: After a quick glance, I think the issue is that you are storing a stack pointer in the array in `AddComp`. So the stack memory gets reused, so you are reading more or less random garbage in the for loop.

Comment: @Ryan1729 I'm trying to store the Component struct objects, which are created by the user. They should be created globally and not deleted as long as the code works. So I don't really think reused memory is the problem here.

Comment: Try (a) getting rid of one layer of indirection (two if you can), or do a smell test to justify why it's there in the first place, or (b) checking the parentheses I mentioned before.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I wanted to answer the other comment before testing the parentheses. I tried the way you showed and I got the _id on code completion. Now it compiles without an error. I spent the last hour to make this line work. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Which method did you end up using? I'll be happy to write up both...

Comment: Welp, I wrote up both.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you so much. Parentheses fixed the compile error but looks like I have problem on accessing the array. I will look through the answers and try to fix the logical errors as well. Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you have loads of indirection that does not appear to be necessary:

```
struct Module
{
    Component **_CompArr[MAX_COMP_COUNT];
    uint8_t _CompCount;

};
```

There is no reason for the second-level pointer in `Component **_CompArr`. You can remove one or two levels of indirection:

1. With single pointers:

   ```
   struct Module
   {
       Component* _CompArr[MAX_COMP_COUNT];
       uint8_t _CompCount;
   };
   ```

   You would use the structure in your loop as

   ```
   if(mod->_CompArr[i]->_id == 0xFF) ...
   ```

   When you assign it, taking an extra refrence is no longer necessary:

   ```
    mod->_CompArr[mod->_CompCount] = _comp;
   ```
2. The second option is to do away with indirection entirely. This may not be as desirable, since it involves copying data, but it would look like this:

   ```
   struct Module
   {
       Component _CompArr[MAX_COMP_COUNT];
       uint8_t _CompCount;
   };
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   if(mod->_CompArr[i]._id == 0xFF) ...
   ```

   And assignment:

   ```
    mod->_CompArr[mod->_CompCount] = *_comp;
   ```

The other alternative is of course to just fix your compiler error. Due to precedence rules, `*(mod->_CompArr[i])->_id` is equivalent to `*((mod->_CompArr[i])->_id)` rather than `(*(mod->_CompArr[i]))->_id`. To get the latter, you have to explicitly include the parentheses as shown.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understood what I was doing wrong (or not right) with the multiple indirections. Your code really helped me understand things. Everything I was trying to make is working right now.

Comment: I used the first method by the way.

Answer (score 0):

- Drop the multiple layers of indirection. If you are just looking to have an array of fixed size, then use an array of fixed size.
- Don't name identifiers starting with an underscore since such names are reserved for the compiler.

Simplified, we get this:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define MAX_COMP_COUNT 64

typedef struct 
{
  uint8_t page;
  uint8_t id;
} Component;

typedef struct 
{
  Component CompArr [MAX_COMP_COUNT];
  uint8_t CompCount;
} Module;
```

Then modify your functions accordingly. It's a mighty weird API to pass a Component as pointer, then fill in the values of that Component struct based on other parameters - don't create weird function interfaces like that! Instead assume that the Component is already filled in by the caller instead:

```
void AddComp (Module* mod, Component* comp)
{
  //Add the component struct to the list on the Module Struct
  mod->CompArr[mod->CompCount] = comp;
  mod->CompCount++;
}
```

---

Alternatively if dynamic allocation is an option:

```
void AddComp (Module* mod, uint8_t page, uint8_t id)
{
  Component* comp = malloc(sizeof *comp);
  comp->page = page;
  comp->id   = id;

  mod->CompArr[mod->CompCount] = comp;
  mod->CompCount++;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that thing about variable names. I will try not to use that kind of naming in the future. Thanks for the help!